# Is it possible to change npm user?

Tags: node.js, github, npm

Editing profile is easy and intuitive but there seem to be username change feature missing. I am trying to find a way to change my npm username from npmjs.com.

The only thing I come up with so far is to register new user, add it to all packages and make it an owner of them.

Is there a way I can simply change my npm user?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'd suggest to contact [npm support](https://www.npmjs.com/support) for this. AFAIK there is no publicly available, official way to change your registered user name.

From my experience, they are very helpful and nice :-)

Answer (score 10):

The npm support told me to **create a new account and move packages manually**. Not great.

So here's a way to move your existing packages to your new account:

1. Log into your old account on both https://www.npmjs.com and [on your bash/zsh terminal](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/adduser)
2. Get a list of your current npm packages:

   1. Go to [your profile on `npmjs.com`](https://www.npmjs.com/~)
   2. Expand the whole list until there's no more "show more packages" button
   3. Run this in your browser's console, it will copy the package names to the clipboard:

      ```js
      copy($$('[href^="/package/"]').map(a => a.textContent).join(' '))
      ```
3. Save the list in a variable in your terminal:

   1. Type `PACKAGES="`
   2. Paste what the space-delimited list of packages you copied earlier
   3. Type `"` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>
4. Add the new user as an owner

   1. Replace `NEW` with your new user’s name, and run this, it will show a preview:

      ```sh
      for PKG in $PACKAGES; do echo npm owner add NEW $PKG; done
      ```
   2. Run the same command you just run, but remove `echo`. This can take a couple of seconds for each package you have. Some packages might require an OTP if you use 2FA

Congratulations! You just added your new account as *owner* of your packages.

Now you can either delete your old npm account, or run that last command again replacing `add NEW` with `remove OLD`, where `OLD` is your old username.